# How to remove header and footer information when printing a web page

Tags: php, html, css, printing

I'm trying the below shown code. but still i'm getting the header and footer on printed page.

show i am tried many css element but i can't remove the header and footer

```
 <style type="text/css" media="print">
  @media print {
    Header {
      display: none !important;
    }
    Footer {
      display: none !important;
    }
    #lrno {
      font-size: 20pt;
      position: absolute!important;
      top: 25px;
      left: 30px;
    }
    #consignor {
      font-size: 30pt;
      position: relative;
      top: 70px;
      left: 0px;
    }
    #consignee {
      font-size: 33pt;
      position: relative;
      top: 9px;
      left: 590px;
    }
  }

</style>




<div id="lrno">
  <?php echo  $sel['lrno']; ?>
</div>
<div id="consignor">
  <?php echo  $sel['cr_name']; ?>
</div>
<div id="consignee">
  <?php echo  $sel['ce_name']; ?>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="btn btn-small red" onclick="PrintDiv()"></button>
</div>
```

I'm getting the footer when printing
[image: I'm getting the footer when printing]

Comment: Are your header and footer sections marked in html?

Comment: @Sail are you using html5 tags?

Comment: Can you show us the full html?

Comment: i don't add any special header and footer item . I only like to remove the browser default header and footer like a url, page title , page number

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, header and footer from browser can set from browser itself. On firefox, you can access from File -> Page Setup then Margin & Header/Footer tab, then set "--blank--" on Header/Footers section.

Comment: This is stackoverflow, not superuser: The question was asked from the perspective of a web developer not that of a browser user.

Comment: Most browser did not allow web developer to control browser.

Answer (score -1):

add thhis class to your header and footer

this media query is working for me

> @media print {
>       .no-print, .no-print *
>       {
>           display: none !important;
>       } }

Comment: The question is asking about the header and footer generated by the browser, not elements that are in the page itself.

Comment: oh :O i think maybe this will help
https://github.com/jquery/standards/issues/9